# How to keep button fixed on a div while background- image of this can rotate. Using Javascript Only?

Tags: javascript

I need a div where a background image will be set but there should be a button on bottom of image (content of same div).

When this button will be click then background image should be rotate **not Button**.

**Is this possible using JavaScript Only?**

this is code sample

```js
function rotate() {
  document.getElementById("img_container").style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg");
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="img_container">
  <button class="btn" onClick="rotate()">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You got responses already when you asked this for the first time, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74488059/1427878 - among them the suggestion that you should do some (proper) research, because this isn't exactly a new topic. So why are you just plainly asking the exact same thing again now?

Comment: @CBroe i didn't get any answer yet. You guys marked it as closed without any reason and no one seeing my question and giving me answer. This is only reason.

Comment: @CBroe and there lots of similar question and its answer but not exactly what i need. I need a solution using JavaScript but they all are solving using CSS.

Comment: The answer below which you just commented _"This is what exactly i need"_ doesn't use JavaScript to solve the problem either. The only bit of JS usage is to _trigger_ the rotation.

Comment: @CBroe I know JS just triggered the rotation function and nothing. But as i told you when i was finding solution then almost all people were suggesting to add psuedo element (::before/::after ) to the class. and this was not a solution for my question since it can't be done by normal javascript click function. But this guy John give me a simplest solution for it and i was surprised.

I don't even understand why you feel so bad. It seems. Just Chill buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this work for you? Create the container where you would have a div with the background image and the rotate button. And then only rotate the div with the image.

```js
function rotate() {
  document.getElementById("img_container").style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  
}

#img_container {
 background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg");
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
  
<div class="container">
  <div id="img_container"></div>
  <button class="btn" onClick="rotate()">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Johny Bhai... tussi great ho yaar . This is what exactly i need.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the button div outside the container div. Since you have kept "btn" inside "container", the button is inheriting all the css of container. Keep the button independent.